# Dynamically read csv files python pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to iteratively read data from a set of csv files in a for loop. 
The csv files are named (`1.csv`, `2.csv` and so on)

The normal way to read the data will be

`data = pd.read_csv('1.csv')`

Please can someone suggest how to replace `1` by `i` when using a `for` loop.

I tried `data = pd.read_csv(i+'.csv')` and `data = pd.read_csv(i'.csv')` but they did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use either percent formatting

```
 pd.read_csv('%d.csv' % i)
```

or `format`

```
 pd.read_csv('{0}.csv'.format(i))
```

Comment: Or use string-concatenation: `pd.read_csv(str(i)+'.csv')` There is nothing bad about it, it's even faster than the format-expression.

Comment: This is actually one of the areas of Python where the Perl mantra "there's more than one way to do it" applies. There's also `'%i'`, you can pass a type specifier to `format`...so many ways!

Answer (score 2):

make a separate string?

if `i` is indeed an integer, using:

```
filename = str(i) + '.csv'
data=pd.read_csv(filename)
```

or even:

```
data=pd.read_csv(str(i)+'.csv')
```

should be fine :)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but FWIW that won't work for an integer ``i``. You'd have to do ``str(i) + '.csv'``.

Comment: There is no information wether `i` is an `int` or a `str`. I don't understand the downvote, too.

Comment: Not downvoter, but I think it is clear in question that i is an integer, so probably that was it. I prefer the other answer though.